# MySQL query to Retrieve Main record from main table and Sub records from another table in a single SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following Two tables

**Table Name: category**

```
categoryid         Categoryname
1                  Mobiles
2                  Laptops
```

**Table Name: product**

```
productid          categoryid         productname
1                  1                  Nokia
2                  2                  Dell
3                  1                  Mi
4                  1                  Samsung
5                  2                  Lenovo
```

Now I am looking for single SQL statement which should retrieve everything in a single sql statement.

Expected output given below:

```
recordtype        categoryid     productid           category       productname
Category          1              0                   Mobiles
Product           1              1                                  Nokia  
Product           1              3                                  Mi
Product           1              4                                  Samsung
Category          2              0                   Laptops
Product           2              2                                  Dell
Product           2              5                                  Lenovo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select 'category' as recordtype, categoryid, 0 as productid, categoryname as category, null as product
from category
union all
select 'product', categoryid, productid, null, productname
from product;
```

Comment: Let me check this.